# How to use panels in applets?

Tags: java, applet, awt

I need to write a strategic game which contains `awt panel`.

**Scenario:-**
Firstly, I need to read from a `txt` file(my map) and draw my images based on the `txt` file. (i did it in the code below).

```
public class temp extends JApplet implements Runnable,MouseListener {

public void init() {
    setSize(1400,800 );
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);

}
@Override
public void start() {
    tilemap = new int[60][75];
    filereader();
    Thread thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();


}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            int mod_i = 100*i;
            int mod_j = 50*j;
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            String str = String.valueOf(tilemap[i][j]);
            g.drawString(str,mod_i,mod_j);

            switch (tilemap[i][j]) {
            case 1:
                g.drawImage(asfalt,mod_i,mod_j,this);
                break;
            case 2://it means everywhere u read 2, so draw a tree
                g.drawImage(tree,mod_i,mod_j,this);
                break;

            }

        }

    }
```

Secondly , i have to divide  my window into 3 parts! (one biggest part, for main background, and 2 small part (one for mini map that will show where I am in the big map and one for showing information) )

**Question:-**
How can I divide it? Should i use panels or borders??
I also have to use containers, as my map is too big and I have to scroll it.

Any suggestions for this scenario? Thanks

Comment: Too much code, nobody's gonna read all that. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and reduce question scope

Comment: that's too mach but easy to understand!

Comment: I'm just trying to help you, do as you like (I didn't downvote, I just reviewed)

Comment: tnx, :) hum....i'll edit it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably not the best idea to write everything in one class. You should definitely store your Filereader in another class.

By the way, do not mix awt and Swing. Either use JApplet and JPanel or Applet and Panel.

Why do you want to use borders? You can use Borders additionally, but that has nothing to do with your structure.

Make a new JPanel where you do all your "main background"-paintig stuff. Call setContentPane of your JApplet to add this JPanel.

Use for example BorderLayout for this JPanel. Create 2 more JPanels for map and information and simply add these JPanels to the main JPanel.

Use the setOpaque - Method of JPanel, if you need transparent background for a JPanel.

If your map (or your mini-map) is static, it might be a good idea, to draw your Images once to a BufferedImage and just draw the BufferedImage.